# How to mute video while playing an mp3 with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a video with audio, and an mp3. I would like to play the video in mute (audio off) while playing an mp3. I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video, and `AVAudioPlayer` to play the mp3. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @nickbona: thank you, i am trying to replace MPMoviePlayerController with AVPlayer: there is any way to find the current video file name that AVPlayer is playing? I am unable to find it.

Comment: (the video is local [it is into the bundle of the app]: also i would like to avoid using metadata [in case it can be possible with videos])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to answer my own question: @nickbona answer was fine but it has no simple and example code.
So the solution is to use AVPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayerController.

So here I am with an easy source code example if someone else will need it:

```
//init player
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"mp4"]] options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *myPlayerController = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];

//disable audio (this is the version when you have more than one video in the playlist: i write this version so it should be more useful)
NSArray *playerTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
NSMutableArray *playerParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in playerTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [playerParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *muteAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[muteAudioMix setInputParameters:playerParams];
[[myPlayerController currentItem] setAudioMix:muteAudioMix];
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController does not appear to give you any control over volume. I would suggest you have a look at [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the accompanying examples. It's a bit more work to play video, but you can use the "muted" property to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Correct, MPMoviePlayerController does not offer such control. But as it uses the app's audio session, you can achieve the same by simply using `MPMusicPlayerController`'s interface even though you are not using it for actual playback.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `MPMusicPlayerController` for achieving what you aim for.

```
- (void)muteVidepPlayer:(BOOL)muteFlag
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    if (muteFlag)
    {
        self.lastVolume = musicPlayer.volume; 
        [musicPlayer setVolume:0.0f];
    }
    else
    {
        [musicPlayer setVolume:self.lastVolume];
    }
}
```

What it does, it uses an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController` which allows you to adjust the volume. Do not get too puzzled, this will effectively adjust the volume of your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance as well. This works because `MPMoviePlayerController` and MPMusicPlayerController both use the app audio session (by default).

For making sure that you are able to reset the volume to the former setup, this method tries to store that value in an instance variable of type `float` (`self.lastVolume`) of your playback controller / viewcontroller / whatever.

Comment: Thank you Till, I am going to try it in a couple of hours.

Comment: I did try your solution, but it doesnt work. (i was also wondering if, in case it was working, that solution will leave the audio on of the AVAduiPlayer object playing an mp3).

Comment: This does not work within the simulator - make sure you test on a device.

Comment: I am now testing the solution using the AVPlayer, there is a bit more code to write but it seems a good solution to me (moreover, it is working :). I was wandering if your solution would let the AVAudioPlayer keep playing the mp3, or if this solution would also mute the AVAudioPlayer.